# Request Filtering is missing from IIS Manager

Tags: iis, iis-7, request-filtering

I have a recently installed Web Server and i want to do some request filtering to stop spam bots requesting contacts.php files and stuff like that. The problem is that i can't find the request filtering option in my IIS Manager.

I was not allowed to post images now but i got proof that it do not show up and the feature is installed ;)

As you see the feature are installed but i just can't see it. Anyone have any idea how i can get it to show up?

I just tried to add the request filtering directly in the web.config and that seems to work fine. At least i do not get an error.

Comment: I do not think the request filtering that i added to my config works either. I only get 404 errors and not 404.7 that i think i am suppose to get.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Just download this and it appears.

http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack

Answer (score 0):

Next time go in add roles and features and select request filtering under Web Server/web server/security